# PHP - MySQL Update if value not set

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following:-

```
    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    if ($fieldBookingdate == NULL) {$fieldBookingdate = 'bookingdate';}
    if ($fieldReturndate == NULL) {$fieldReturndate = 'returndate';}
    if ($fieldBookingtime == NULL) {$fieldBookingtime = 'bookingtime';}
    if ($fieldReturntime == NULL) {$fieldReturntime = 'returntime';}
    if ($fieldPassengername == NULL) {$fieldPassengername = 'passengername';}
    if ($fieldPassengeremail == NULL) {$fieldPassengeremail = 'passengeremail';}
    if ($fieldPaddress == NULL) {$fieldPaddress = 'paddress';}
    if ($fieldVaddress == NULL) {$fieldVaddress = 'vaddress';}
    if ($fieldDaddress == NULL) {$fieldDaddress = 'daddress';}
    if ($fieldCartype == NULL) {$fieldCartype = 'cartype';}
    if ($fieldFlightnumber == NULL) {$fieldFlightnumber = 'flightnumber';}
    if ($fieldComments == NULL) {$fieldComments = 'comments';}

    $this->sql = "UPDATE  tblbookings SET bookingdate = '$fieldBookingdate', returndate = '$fieldReturndate', bookingtime = '$fieldBookingtime'
    returntime = '$fieldReturntime', passengername = '$fieldPassengername', passengeremail = '$fieldPassengeremail', paddress = '$fieldPaddress'
    vaddress = '$fieldVaddress', daddress = '$fieldDaddress', cartype = '$fieldCartype', flightnumber = '$fieldFlightnumber', comments = '$fieldComments' WHERE
    bookref = '$fieldBookingreference';";
```

Basically the `UPDATE` will amend 12 database fields, but it may be that only 11 values have been set. (MySQL)

For values not set I know you can update like `UPDATE tblbookings SET bookingdate = bookingdate` and it will work. However, because I have these values within quotes in the query it is updating as `UPDATE tblbookings SET bookingdate = 'bookingdate'` - and failing.

How could I get this to work?

UPDATE 1:-

Example;

```
UPDATE  tblbookings SET bookingdate = 'bookingdate' WHERE

        bookref = 'BR1360'
```

I get the following error:-

## 1292 - Incorrect date value: 'bookingdate' for column 'bookingdate' at row 133

If I do:-

```
UPDATE  tblbookings SET bookingdate = bookingdate WHERE

        bookref = 'BR1360'
```

This will work, and leave bookingdate value as it is.

Comment: The query is not failing for the reason you think. It might fail because some of your variables are set and they are not properly escaped (probably one of more of them contains a quote). You should try to print your query before submitting to the database to see where the error is.

Comment: Are you escaping that data at all? Like @Fabio says, it might be that the data being passed is creating an invalid query. If you're using PDO you should be binding those parameters. That's kind of what PDO is for.

Comment: Here is the SQL response: `UPDATE  tblbookings SET bookingdate = 'bookingdate', returndate = 'returndate', bookingtime = 'bookingtime'

        returntime = 'returntime', passengername = 'passengername', passengeremail = 'passengeremail', paddress = 'paddress'

        vaddress = 'vaddress', daddress = 'daddress', cartype = 'ExecEst1', flightnumber = 'flightnumber', comments = '123' WHERE

        bookref = 'BR1360';`

Comment: Just to add, it updates if I update all 12 records

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by a missing comma in your query

```
bookingtime = '$fieldBookingtime'    returntime = '$fieldReturntime', 
                               //^ here the comma is missing
```

So the composer is trying to set the `bookingtime` column as `'fieldBookingtime'    returntime...`, it's like you are passing characters that are not escaped by quote.

As I already explained in my comment the query is not failing because of the quote you used as you thought.

Comment: That is one of the problems, I now have the following:-

`Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: 'bookingdate' for column 'bookingdate' at row 133SQL: UPDATE  tblbookings SET bookingdate = 'bookingdate', returndate = 'returndate', bookingtime = 'bookingtime',

Because it is trying to set an empty field to 'bookingtime' instead of bookingtime if the value is not set.

Comment: this is probably due to the column `bookingdate` being a datetime column and not a varchar, you are trying to set it is as varchar.

Comment: If the value is not set, I want the update to be `bookingdate = bookingdate` which will keep the value the same, and update all the other values

Comment: but because it may be updating values I have to put them between quotations, I was wondering if there was a way to remove the quotations for the values that are not set

Comment: you need the quotation not because values are not set but because you insert characters (varchar columns). Datetime columns instead expect data to be passed as `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: But if I do `bookingdate = bookingdate` in phpMyAdmin it updates the record and leaves the value as it was previously, which is what I am wanting it to do

Comment: this is because with phpmyadmin you update as the data already contained in the column, what you are trying to do with php is set it as literaly `bookingdate`

Comment: I managed to get it working as follows:-
`if ($fieldBookingdate == NULL) {$fieldBookingdate = "bookingdate = bookingdate";} else {$fieldBookingdate = "bookingdate = '$fieldBookingdate'";}`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working as follows:-

```
if ($fieldBookingdate == NULL) {$fieldBookingdate = "bookingdate = bookingdate";} else {$fieldBookingdate = "bookingdate = '$fieldBookingdate'";}
```

So if the value is not set, it will leave the field as it is (`bookingdate = bookingdate`), for the values that are set it will update them as (`$fieldBookingdate = "bookingdate = '$fieldBookingdate'";`)